# How to connect RSTP with OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, face-recognition

Hi I try to connect OpenCV, Face recognition Library with my RSTP CCTV. But when i run my code i getting an error like below. Hope someone can help me regarding on this issue. I attach here my code

**Error:**

> [h264 @ 000002a9659dba00] error while decoding MB 10 94, bytestream -5
> [h264 @ 000002a953c1e2c0] Invalid NAL unit 8, skipping. Traceback
> (most recent call last):   File "face-present.py", line 125, in
>
> cv2.imshow('Video', frame) cv2.error: OpenCV(4.0.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:350:
> error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in
> function 'cv::imshow'

**mycode.py**

```
import face_recognition
import cv2

video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp://admin:adam12345@192.168.0.158:554/Streaming/channels/101")
roy_image = face_recognition.load_image_file("images/roy1.jpg")
roy_face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(roy_image,num_jitters=100)[0]

# Load a second sample picture and learn how to recognize it.
henrik_image = face_recognition.load_image_file("images/Mr_henrik.jpg")
henrik_face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(henrik_image,num_jitters=100)[0]

stefan_image = face_recognition.load_image_file("images/stefan.jpg")
stefan_face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(stefan_image,num_jitters=100)[0]

hairi_image = face_recognition.load_image_file("images/Hairi.jpeg")
hairi_face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(hairi_image,num_jitters=100)[0]

syam_image = face_recognition.load_image_file("images/syam1.jpeg")
syam_face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(syam_image,num_jitters=100)[0]
#print(syam_face_encoding)


# Create arrays of known face encodings and their names
known_face_encodings = [
    roy_face_encoding,
    stefan_face_encoding,
    henrik_face_encoding,
    hairi_face_encoding,
    syam_face_encoding
]
known_face_names = [
    "roy",
    "stefan",
    "henrik",
    "hairi",
    "syam"

]


# Initialize some variables
face_locations = []
face_encodings = []
face_names = []
process_this_frame = True

# # Process video frame frequency
# process_frame_freq = 4
# process_this_frame = process_frame_freq

while True:
    if video_capture.isOpened():
        # Grab a single frame of video
        ret, frame = video_capture.read()
        if ret:
            # Resize frame of video to 1/4 size for faster face recognition processing
            small_frame = cv2.resize(frame, None, fx=0.25, fy=0.25)

        # Convert the image from BGR color (which OpenCV uses) to RGB color (which face_recognition uses)
        rgb_small_frame = small_frame[:, :, ::-1]

        # Only process every other frame of video to save time
        if process_this_frame:
            # Find all the faces and face encodings in the current frame of video
            face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(rgb_small_frame)
                
            if face_locations:     #  prevent manipulation of null variable
                top, right, bottom, left = face_locations[0]
                # faces_recognized += 1
                # print("[%i] Face recognized..." % faces_recognized)
                cv2.rectangle(frame, (left, top), (right, bottom), (0, 0, 255), 2)
                cropped_face = frame[top:bottom, left:right]

            face_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(rgb_small_frame, face_locations)
            #print(face_encodings)


            face_names = []
            for face_encoding in face_encodings:
                # See if the face is a match for the known face(s)
                matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(known_face_encodings, face_encoding,tolerance=0.5)
                name = "Unknown"

                # If a match was found in known_face_encodings, just use the first one.
                if True in matches:
                    first_match_index = matches.index(True)
                    name = known_face_names[first_match_index]
                    print(name)
                        
                face_names.append(name)

        process_this_frame = not process_this_frame


        # Display the results
        for (top, right, bottom, left), name in zip(face_locations, face_names):
            # Scale back up face locations since the frame we detected in was scaled to 1/4 size
            top *= 4
            right *= 4
            bottom *= 4
            left *= 4

            # Draw a box around the face
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (left, top), (right, bottom), (0, 0, 255), 2)

            # Draw a label with a name below the face
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (left, bottom - 35), (right, bottom), (0, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)
            font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX
            cv2.putText(frame, name, (left + 6, bottom - 6), font, 1.0, (255, 255, 255), 1)

        #Display the resulting image
        cv2.imshow('Video', frame)

        # Hit 'q' on the keyboard to quit!
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    
# Release handle to the webcam
video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: ignore empty images. Sometimes you will need multie reads until you get a valid image. Seen that behaviour on several cameras.

Comment: @Micka, the problem my the camera become freeze after the error is displayed

Comment: does the camera freeze or does your program freeze? Did you add the code part for "ignoring empty frames"? They may not be processed (no resizing, no imshow etc.)

Comment: The camerea freeze. Can you help me how to put "ignoring empty frames"?

Comment: not in Python... maybe if you put all your folliwing code in the `if ret:` part